# Swift iOS Youtube embedded video not playing

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, embed

I have a simple page in my iOS app that has one `UIWebView`. The `UIWebView` is supposed to load an Youtube video. The problem is when I go to the page, the webview load the correct video preview, but when I click on the play button, nothing happens. I looked at bunch of tutorials and youtube videos on this topic, and looking at them, it doesn't see like I am doing anything wrong. I wonder if there is a need for setting some permission on plist life, even though I didn't find any reference anywhere. 
 My app is on Xcode 7.3, swift 2. Please help. Here is the code for my viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class watchVideoVC: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {



    @IBOutlet weak var myVid: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = "https://youtube.com/embed/tVjv8I0BlU4"
        self.myVid.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        let fbor = "0"
        let height = myVid.frame.height
        let width = myVid.frame.width
        let code:NSString = "<iframe src=\(myURL) width=\(width) height=\(height) frameborder=\(fbor) allowfullscreen></iframe>"
        self.myVid.loadHTMLString(code as String, baseURL: nil)
       }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Some time video didn't play, because many video are restricted to play into 3rd party application. those videos can only play in native Youtube only. So..

Add below code into your swift file. It will prompt native error message

```
player.delegate = self 
func playerViewDidBecomeReady(_ playerView: YTPlayerView)
{
    playerView.playVideo()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind showing the actual youtube video page (not the own video embedded, I mean), you can just load the youtube URL in the webview:

`self.myVid.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:myUrl)!))`

Other than that, I think you might give a try to the Youtube IFrame API, which uses a small javascript to render the iframe and set the actions accordingly (You'll probably have to add the whole HTML given in the example to the webview to make it work).

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Finally, if you want the video to autostart, you might probably add below `allowsInlineMediaPlayback`:

`self.myVid.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false`

Comment: Thanks. I do want to make it an embedded video, because there will be other actions and labels added to the page. About the iframe_api, I am not very sure how to implement js in Swift. I need to do some research on that.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found help from another forum and was guided to the "youtube-ios-player". The gihub link for it is https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper
 The github link had some instructions which are outdated, since it used reference to Objective C instead of Swift. But I also got help from a youtube video explaining how to use "youtube-ios-player-helper​" with Swift 2. The link of the video is :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAAZJm6H9Ms​ 
   Instead of using CocoaPods, I used manual method of copying files. The details of how to do it is explained in the youtube video mentioned above and also in the github link.
  Using this "youtube-ios-player-helper​", my embedded youtube video loads and plays perfectly.